# GoQuorum: network configuration change - hard fork required?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, quorum, hardforks, permissioned-chain

I've created a GoQuorum network and I'm looking for ways to change the way the network operates in future, while also preserving the blockchain when I do so.

From the [GoQuorum docs](https://consensys.net/docs/goquorum/en/stable/configure-and-manage/configure/consensus-protocols/qbft/) I know that the `"transitions"` field in `genesis.json` is supposed to enable changes starting with block `x`. However, this feature is not well documented. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/ConsenSys/quorum/blob/master/params/config.go#L700) I gather what specifically can be changed.

Now I wonder about **other params**, like the `gasLimit` per block. This is not a parameter that can be included in the `"transitions"` field, so how would I change it?

Would this necessarily require a hard fork?

If so, how do I create a hard fork for this purpose? What can vs. cannot change in a `genesis.json` if the goal is to **keep the genesis block** as it is?

I'm familiar with the [GoQuorum docs](https://consensys.net/docs/goquorum/en/stable/reference/genesis/#configuration-items) on the `genesis.json`. I reckon that certain genesis params must remain as they are (like `"alloc"`, as shown in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962148/ethereum-private-network-dynamic-genesis-json-alloc)), while some fields in `"config"`, e.g. the ones referring to scheduled hard fork blocks, can be changed without affecting the genesis block. Is this correct?

I'm also aware of the official geth docs on [private networks](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/private-network), but quorum seems to handle fields like `"constantinopleFixBlock"` differently. The [docs](https://consensys.net/docs/goquorum/en/stable/reference/genesis/#configuration-items) state:
*In private networks, the milestone block defines the protocol version for the network.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way geth handles hard forks is different. Generally speaking geth will have a a bunch of changes at a block height that are irreversible.

With Quorum we wanted to be more flexible with things and started introducing the idea of transitions in `v22.4`. You're right the docs are out of date in some cases. At the moment you can specify a transition for any of the following.

https://github.com/ConsenSys/quorum/blob/master/params/config.go#L451

```
type Transition struct {
Block                        *big.Int              `json:"block"`
Algorithm                    string                `json:"algorithm,omitempty"`
EpochLength                  uint64                `json:"epochlength,omitempty"`                  // Number of blocks that should pass before pending validator votes are reset
BlockPeriodSeconds           uint64                `json:"blockperiodseconds,omitempty"`           // Minimum time between two consecutive IBFT or QBFT blocks’ timestamps in seconds
EmptyBlockPeriodSeconds      *uint64               `json:"emptyblockperiodseconds,omitempty"`      // Minimum time between two consecutive IBFT or QBFT a block and empty block’ timestamps in seconds
RequestTimeoutSeconds        uint64                `json:"requesttimeoutseconds,omitempty"`        // Minimum request timeout for each IBFT or QBFT round in milliseconds
ContractSizeLimit            uint64                `json:"contractsizelimit,omitempty"`            // Maximum smart contract code size
ValidatorContractAddress     common.Address        `json:"validatorcontractaddress"`               // Smart contract address for list of validators
Validators                   []common.Address      `json:"validators"`                             // List of validators
ValidatorSelectionMode       string                `json:"validatorselectionmode,omitempty"`       // Validator selection mode to switch to
EnhancedPermissioningEnabled *bool                 `json:"enhancedPermissioningEnabled,omitempty"` // aka QIP714Block
PrivacyEnhancementsEnabled   *bool                 `json:"privacyEnhancementsEnabled,omitempty"`   // privacy enhancements (mandatory party, private state validation)
PrivacyPrecompileEnabled     *bool                 `json:"privacyPrecompileEnabled,omitempty"`     // enable marker transactions support
GasPriceEnabled              *bool                 `json:"gasPriceEnabled,omitempty"`              // enable gas price
MinerGasLimit                uint64                `json:"miner.gaslimit,omitempty"`               // Gas Limit
TwoFPlusOneEnabled           *bool                 `json:"2FPlus1Enabled,omitempty"`               // Ceil(2N/3) is the default you need to explicitly use 2F + 1
TransactionSizeLimit         uint64                `json:"transactionSizeLimit,omitempty"`         // Modify TransactionSizeLimit
BlockReward                  *math.HexOrDecimal256 `json:"blockReward,omitempty"`                  // validation rewards
BeneficiaryMode              *string               `json:"beneficiaryMode,omitempty"`              // Mode for setting the beneficiary, either: list, besu, validators (beneficiary list is the list of validators)
MiningBeneficiary            *common.Address       `json:"miningBeneficiary,omitempty"`            // Wallet address that benefits at every new block (besu mode)
```

Note `MinerGasLimit`

You could in theory perform a transition with an alloc at a block height, but it's not implemented.